# Excel M x N matrix MULTIPLY numbers in same row and return an array But Don't MULTIPLY all

Tags: arrays, excel, array-formulas

0.6 0.4 0.5 =>> 0.12

0.4 0.8 0.5 =>> 0.16

the size of M x N matrix, which is a return of array formula, is not fixed.
I know there is PRODUCT, but it just gives me a single number of multiplication of all numbers. I need an array of the multiplication of numbers in each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your matrix starting from C1, and you enter your formula from A1, then it'll be:

`{=PRODUCT(OFFSET(C1,ROW()-1,0,1,COUNT(C1:XFD1)))}`

Some notes on it:

- it's an array formula, working only if you enter to the whole range, so:

  - select a range which will be likely big enough to host data for all rows of the matrix, like A1:A50
  - enter the formula in A1
  - press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- it'll work correctly only if there is no data from the right of your matrix
- of course calculations can be at different location compared to your matrix, just make sure to adapt references accordingly.
- the matrix should be complete (all rows has the same number of columns)